# Subscribe is not a function Angular

Tags: angular, observable, angular-components

I am trying to return the value while subscribing and I am getting the value also but getting the error also

** Inside Service **

```
getColumnValueg(): Observable<any>
{  console.log("service",this.colValueg);
   return (this.colValueg);
}
```

** FormComponent **

```
ngOnInit()
{
  // perform the task of sending and receiving value.
  console.log("inint form-lib component",this.UserFormArray);

  this.UserFormArray = this.service.getFormDetails();

  this.service.getColumnValueg().subscribe(data => this.g1 = data);
  this.service.getColumnValueg().subscribe(data => this.lg1 = data);
  this.service.getColumnValueg().subscribe(data => this.md1 = data);

  console.log('userformarray',this.UserFormArray);
  console.log(this.g1,this.lg1,this.md1);
}
```

but data is not getting called after that I called these service method from a button click event then it showed the value. I am getting the error to subscribe is not a function. I tried using of, from it's not working.
I am trying to fetch value on page load but i am not able to fetch data on page load

**Edited** 
The problem is solved but the next problem raised is that I am not able to fetch the value on nginit

Comment: what's the value of `this.colValueg`

Comment: number it can be 12,11,13

Comment: ha! I see, do something like this instead `return Observable.of(this.colValueg)`

Comment: gave me the error Observable module has no export member

Comment: yeah, check @SiddAjmera's answer for the right import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Change your method which returns the `Observable`

```
getColumnValueg(): Observable<any>
{  console.log("service",this.colValueg);
   return Observable.of(this.colValueg);
}
```

OR

```
getColumnValueg(): Observable<any>
{  console.log("service",this.colValueg);
   return of(this.colValueg);
}
```

### Change in ngOnInit

```
   ngOnInit()
    {
      // perform the task of sending and receiving value.
      console.log("inint form-lib component",this.UserFormArray);

      this.UserFormArray = this.service.getFormDetails();

      this.service.getColumnValueg().subscribe(data => {
          console.log(" ColumnValue data " , data);
      });

      console.log('userformarray',this.UserFormArray);
      console.log(this.g1,this.lg1,this.md1);
    }
```

Demo link is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-srabjg

Comment: can you provide import of, Observable and of ....??? because i have tried it but it has not worked out

Comment: @Dexter'sWebLab try this **import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';**

Comment: module has no export member Observable

Comment: i am sending number,string not array

Comment: I added integer for demo, if you are using the string that should be fine as well.

Comment: but the problem is that on nginit its not fetching the value

Comment: Check updated answer. Modified `ngOnInit` function where you can get the data in subscribe section. You should fetch the data inside this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `this.colValueg` is not an Observable. You'll have to convert it into one. You can use `of` to do that:

**If you're using Rxjs6:**

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
...
colValueg = 'Some Value';
...
getColumnValueg(): Observable < any > {
  console.log("service", this.colValueg);
  return of(this.colValueg);
}
```

**If you're using Rxjs5:**

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
...
colValueg = 'Some Value';
...
getColumnValueg(): Observable < any > {
  console.log("service", this.colValueg);
  return Observable.of(this.colValueg);
}
```

Comment: but the problem is that on nginit its not fetching the value

Comment: Where exactly are you setting/initializing  `colValueg` in your service? I seriously feel you've not provided enough information in your question. If would be great if you could create a [Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) replicating this issue.

Comment: there is a method in service when it get called it get the value

Comment: ya wil create a project and upload it and upload the link

Comment: I asked about where is `colValueg` setting/initializing?

Comment: inside service its getting set and initialized

Comment: tried to upload code but giving lot of error so resolving it

Comment: how to load a whole component when value is received ?\